# Designing a reusable List-Detail view in React

Tags: reactjs

Creating a list-detail view in React isn't difficult, but I'm trying to make a reusable component. My component currently looks like

```js
import React from 'react';

class SplitView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebar: props.sidebar,
            main: props.main,
            focused: false
        }
    }

    shouldDismiss() {
        this.setState({focused: false});
    }

    shouldFocus() {
        this.setState({focused: true});
    }

    render() {
        const SidebarView = this.state.sidebar;
        const MainView = this.state.main;
        
        return (<div class={`SplitView ${this.state.focused ? 'MainViewVisible' : ''}`}>
            <div class='SplitViewSidebar'>
                <SidebarView shouldFocusCallback={ this.shouldFocus } />
            </div>
            <div class='SplitViewMain'>
                <MainView shouldDismissCallback={ this.shouldDismiss } />
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default SplitView;
```

And my dummy render function looks like

```js
return (<SplitView sidebar={(<div>Hello World</div>)} main={(<div>Main World</div>)} />);
```

This gives me the error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

So I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'm just too inexperienced with React to know what exactly it is. Google hasn't been particularly helpful.

Comment: What is SidebarView and MainView? Which GUI lib are you using?
"class" or "className"?

Comment: They are defined a couple lines above. The goal is to be able to add properties to the components that were passed as properties. The child components need to be able to instruct the SplitView to do things, so I'm trying to give them handlers.

Comment: May you reproduce it in https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do well here with some form of a prop that renders passed in HTML. I can see you've tried this already by passing in HTML directly and I can't speak for certain whether this is supported in React but I know you can do this with functions.

For example here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kjscott27/pen/LYGBMeg)

Basically you're creating a functional component and passing it to your reusable component to call the function and render the HTML. So Based on the above if you change your dummy render to this:

Wasn't sure what the passed functions were doing so I just left them unused, my CodePen has an example of a console.log being passed through one of the meta contents.

```
return (<SplitView sidebar={(shouldFocusCallback) => <div>Hello World</div>} main={(shouldDismissCallback) => <div>Main World</div>)} />);
```

You could also then apply this change:

```
<div class='SplitViewSidebar'>
  {sidebar(this.shouldFocus)}
</div>
<div class='SplitViewMain'>
  {main(this.shouldDismiss)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, passing it as a function was what I was missing.

Comment: Excellent dude, happy you're on your way!